# Why does my file URL (with relative path) fail even when using stringByExpandingTildeInPath:?

Tags: objective-c, macos, file-io, path

I'm trying to create a valid file URL which points to a file which I know exists.

```
NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[@"~/Users/zak/global.scss" 
stringByExpandingTildeInPath] isDirectory:NO];
NSLog(@"Looks like you want me to open a %@ file!", fileURL.pathExtension);

NSError *err;
if (![fileURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&err]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", err);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"success!!!");
};
```

which always causes the compiler to keep telling me

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “global.scss” couldn’t be 
opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x1021937a0 {NSURL=file://
localhost/~/Users/zak/global.scss, 
NSFilePath=/~/Users/zak/global.scss, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x10212f4b0 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
No such file or directory"}
```

Why doesn't this work? Do I need to use some sort of constant as the base URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~/Users/zak/globals.scss` almost certainly does *not* exist.  That `~` is in a pretty weird looking place. You might try `~zak/global.scss` or `/Users/zak/globals.scss`.  To check the path, just do `ls PATHTOTEST` in a terminal window - it will tell you if it's there or not (and show you the expansion of the path if it failed).